# HTML page not displaying the image

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `JavaScript` file:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
image = new Image();
image.src = 'abc.jpg';
image.onload = function(){
    var cols = image.width;
    var rows = image.width;
    canvas.width = cols;
    canvas.height = rows;
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
};
```

The `HTML` file looks as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>chapter1</title>
    <script src="matrix.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>   
</body>
</html>
```

But, when I try to view the HTML page, I don't see the image, provided that all the files including the image are in the same directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: var rows = image.height

Comment: works ok -- https://jsfiddle.net/4wzjvhrw/ -- open your browser console and check for errors

Comment: I get a long list of errors, things like that: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:6853/callback.json?find_port=1&_=1446243272764. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Comment: I also tested, works perfectly fine